# uniform not seen as referenced on shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working with openGL.
I have vertex and fragment shaders that work fine when used just with each other, but when I add the tesselation shaders, uniforms that were previously recognized on the program are said to be not referenced in the shaders.

Is this an specificity that I'm not aware about?

This is in my .cpp:

```
program = new Shader("tessVshader.glsl", "tessFshader.glsl", "tessGshader.glsl");
// Removed tesselation specific just to try to compile w/ geo shader
...
program->SetUniform("Modelview", model * view);
program->SetUniform("NormalMatrix", normalMatrix);
```

And this is tessGshader.glsl first lines:

```
uniform mat4 Modelview;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
```

This is the output:

```
Uniform Modelview is not referenced in the shaders.
```

Comment: Are you recompiling everything properly? Maybe show some code.

Comment: You need to provide code before we can know why that uniform was referenced or not.

Comment: Best guess -- addition of the tessellation shader causes the link to fail (due to a bug in the shader), which causes all uniforms to appear unused (as there's no complete shader program)

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Shader class written by you? If yes, some of its code would be helpful.
If GL shader objects are properly created, make sure that you have a call to glUseProgram(...) before trying to access the uniforms. Otherwise openGL will be unable to find them.
And btw, ensure that you can see compile/linking time errors in your glsl code. Look up the function glGetInfoLog, if you dont use it already.